# How do I add a column in mysql using python by taking the input of the user of what the column name should be

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy, jupyter

How do I add a column or multiple columns by asking the user for input and adding the columns based on that in mysql using python?

I tried using the for loop and %s but that doesn't seem to work here

Comment: Do you have the code for what you have tried?

Comment: i was trying something along the lines of:  print(df.head(1))
                m=input("enter the number of columns you want to be created:")
                for i in m:
                 print("Enter name of the columns value")
                 nval=input()
                 ninsert[nval]=""
                 print(ninsert)
                df1=pd.DataFrame(ninsert, index=[0])
                query="ALTER TABLE pokemon_stats ADD " i thot of creatng a new tble with this dataframe df1 & concate it with the previos tble bt im still stuck on how to take the names added by input as column names

Comment: Edit the question, rather than writing code in the comments!

Comment: MYSQL insists on a valid datatype - which you don't appear to be providing..

Comment: Are you modifying a pandas dataframe or a mysql table? Or both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
name_table="beep"
table_structure=("big","small")
e="create table"+name_table+"("
table_structure=list(table_structure)
for i in range(len(table_structure)):
    e=e+' '+table_structure[i]+' varchar(50),'   
g=e[0:-1]
g=g+')'
mycursor.execute(g)
mycon.commit()
```

Comment: The question is about modifying an existing table, not creating a new table.

Comment: Use `join()` instead of a loop that contatenates.